# Powershell: How do I edit a string between strings while that string has a random set of numbers

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I am trying to create a powershell script that will change some lines in a text file on several computers. Currently, the password is a group of random numbers and letters that are different for each text file but the new password will be the same.

I am using Powershell v2 and 3.

Recap:

1) Change the string between "password" and "serial_number"

2) The string "/*57575757hsdhdh" for example is a bunch of random numbers and letters which is different for each text file. That I want changed to "/*123456" for all text files.

3) Also, at the end of the text I want to change the username from "ABC" TO "DEF"

4) Here is the Text file:

```
{
   "http_proxy_password" : "/*21126D837687BDE38B4A85A9D6977E0243246C194934A564DE653DAFF556D5A1",
   "http_proxy_username" : "",
   "password" : "/*57575775hsdhdh",
   "serial_number" : "65456N",
   "socks_password" : "/*5C1F18F57883BC94FE3B82DFD1957973A422E1BFD1BFB5F0938AC2B726A53858",
   "socks_username" : "",
   "username" : "ABC"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this looks like a `json` file for me, except for the missing `}` which you probably forgot.

To read the file, you can use the [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) cmdlet. With the [ConvertFrom-Json](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=217031) cmdlet, you can convert the string into a `json` object.  Then you can access and modify the desired properties and finally convert it back to a `json` string using [ConvertTo-Json](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=217032):

```
$contennt =  Get-Content 'Your_file_path_here'

$object = $contennt | ConvertFrom-Json
$object.password = '/*123456'
$object.username = 'DEF'
$object | ConvertTo-Json
```

*Output:*

```
{
    "http_proxy_password":  "/*21126D837687BDE38B4A85A9D6977E0243246C194934A564DE653DAFF556D5A1",
    "http_proxy_username":  "",
    "password":  "/*123456",
    "serial_number":  "65456N",
    "socks_password":  "/*5C1F18F57883BC94FE3B82DFD1957973A422E1BFD1BFB5F0938AC2B726A53858",
    "socks_username":  "",
    "username":  "DEF"
}
```

**Note**: If you want to write the `json` back to the file, you can use the [Set-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113392) cmdlet.